# How to find which classes implement a particular interface in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I have an application as JAR file with many dependencies. For some reason I need to decompile one of the libraries and open it up with Eclipse. For a given interface in the project, is there a way to find the class(s) that implements it? It may be the case that the interface was implemented in other library that I didn't decompile yet. Is it possible to do this for this kind of classes?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Right-click on the interface, and choose "Open type hierarchy". Then click on "Show the subtype hierarchy".

Comment: It didn't show me anything, when I click on "Show the subtype hierarchy" I just see the Interface not the class implemented it.

Comment: Then it means that no class in the Java Build Path of the project implements this interface. Eclipse of course has to know about the potential classes: the jar file containing them must be in the Java Build Path of the project.

Comment: You mean I must Add Other jar file to Java Build Path?

Comment: Yes, of course. Eclipse only knows about the classes in the classpath. It won't scan your entire hard disk to find some class implementing your interface.

Comment: I add other Jar file to my Java Build Path but still didn't show me the implementation. and I am sure some class implements it because via Reflection I can use it.

Answer (score 47):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> after selecting the classname; should work in Java Perspective.

Answer (score 10):

You can "Show Type Hierarchy" on the item (Right Click to choose this option or press <kbd>F4</kbd> when the item is highlighted)*.

However, this will list only items in those projects that are referred ("dependent"). Not in others.

So if you have decompiled a jar, and there is another jar that you have not decompiled, then the implementations (of the interface) in that jar will not be listed.

Also, say you have decompiled a jar as a project and there is another project that is referring to the jar, and not the decompiled project, implementations in that will also not be listed.

So you will have to decompile all jars and add them as projects (and add references via "Java Build Path") to make sure all the implementations in the jars of your choice are listed.

<sub>* Quick type Hierarchy, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>T</kbd>  will show a similar structure in a tooltip/autocomplete kind of panel. But the complete type hierarchy is more useful for the type of analysis you are intending to do.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

There is radio-button "Implementors" in Java Search.

Comment: How does it not answer the question? Open Java Search, enter the interface name, click "Implementors" and you will "find which classes implement a particular interface."

Answer (score 1):

Or right-click and select `Quick Type Hierarchy` for a pulldown menu of extending interfaces and implementing classes.

Comment: When I right-click and select Quick Type Hierarchy I just see the Interface not the class implemented it

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + H (Search Option) Open Java Search perspective and, enter the interface name, click Implementors radio button and you will find which classes implement a particular interface. Same as answer from stackexchanger above

Answer (score 0):

Select the class name, then 'F4' in Eclipse (Windows environment)